# mail attachment not working in vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net

I am trying to create memory stream variable  and using that first i am trying write file in local C: location then I am trying to create mail attachment object and passing in to my send email function .

Some how after receiving email i am getting pdf file in attachment but its not opening and getting message invalid pdf like. below is my sample code

```
If Not m Is Nothing Then
                        Dim file As New FileStream(FilePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write)
                        m.WriteTo(file)
                        file.Close()

                        Dim ma As New System.Net.Mail.Attachment(m, "track" & dt1.Rows(0)("abc").ToString & ".pdf")
                        attach(0) = ma
                    End If
MF.Email(s, ST, internalEmail, "" & internalEmail, "" & internalEmail, "" & internalEmail, attach)
```

Comment: Tough to say without knowing anything about the MF object.  Check this out though: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9b46af9f(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: MF.email function doing all mail attachment formalited as per your link ..so i am good their i am also getting email and pdf in attachment but  attachment not opening

Comment: You should show us that code too.

Comment: got solution ...I was missing to set  stream position to zero .after reading  file one time when i was trying to read again. I need to set position to zero then only attachment will get data and pdf will get open,.

Comment: Cool, you might also be interested in System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes